Is there a difference between rotation about axis and rotation around axis?
I cannot find a clear answer to my question.
So far my presumption is that rotation around axis is self explanatory, though rotation about axis is a rotation “parallel” to the axis as shown in the following image:


This is not really a mathematical question, more a question about English terminology.

I get the same question from my students often... perhaps we can migrate this to English.SE?

I think they mean the same thing. When you encounter either one in context the context should make the meaning clear.

No one with a good taste of English language rotates something "about" an axis. Only mathematicians do that. It can't be helped.

I was not sure if that has anything to do with engineering/geometry etc. One of my engineers treated about and around as two separate things. But some engineers treat them as one and the same thing. That’s why I thought to ask a community of professionals, to make sure that I am not making a mistake. I have to often describe 3D orientation of a wafer that has 3 axes. Before the wafer is cut, quite often, it gets rotated several times cw/ccw around/about one or two axes on certain angles.
